# Facebook Graph API and sharing video on Android having issues showing video

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

We are using Latest Android SDK and using graph API we are sharing Videos and Images. All are working correctly on all phones except Samsung Galaxy 6 and that also when logged in through one facebook account, if I log out and login with another account then it is working fine. Sharing an Image is not having any issues, when video is shared on facebook using Graph API, we are  getting success callback without any error, but after few seconds Facebook App is showing error message as shown in screenshot.

[image]

It seems to be some bug with facebook API as it is returning success whereas video is not getting shared, we are confused because on same phone when we login using different FB account and share it worked.

Comment: So Facebook team replied that its issue at their end regarding some encoding of video which is causing posting issue.